# Вход под Администратором

Tags: windows, windows-7, администрирование

Как войти под пользователем Администратор в Windows 7 при запуске компьютера?

Answer (score 2):

Не понятно, какого именно ты администратора имеешь ввиду. По умолчанию в системе один пользователь и он является администратором. Чтобы он стал "Супер администратором" достаточно отключить службу UAC (служба контроля учетных записей) в управление пользователями.

Если имеется ввиду, чтобы система не просила вводить пароль администратора (пользователя) на странице приветствия, или же, в случае зарегистрированных нескольких пользователей не просила выбирать их, а автоматически авторизовалась с указанного, то можно это сделать тут: <пуск>/<Выполнить> набрать команду без кавычек: "control userpasswords2" нажать Enter. Снять опцию "требовать пароль", выбрать пользователя, нажать ОК. В случае необходимости, указать пароль, который требуется для авторизации выбранного вами пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Зайти под пользователем - добавить пользователя в группу "Администраторы" - зайти под пользователем с правами администратора.

Answer (score 1):

Можно также убрать ограничения по установке ПО и пр. Все это делается в панели управления

Answer (score 1):

«Пуск» -> «Стандартные» -> «Командная строка»ПрКнМыш на этом пункте.Выберите «Запуск от имени Администратора».В открывшемся окне введите команду: net user администратор /active:yesпрезагрузка, в окне приветствия добавится администратор, ур-р-ря-я-а-а-а...

Answer (score 0):

При входе в "*безопасном режиме*" (**F8** при загрузке) в окне приветствия высвечивается 2 штуки:

- юзер (если ты один или оба, или три...)
- администратор - это такой себе "невидимый" администратор в обычном режиме.

от теперь и зайди и вытворяй чего получится!